# Admob live Ad not working in Beta release

Tags: admob

My App doesn't show the live Ads after deploying it to Beta release. It always show the test Ad instead. I also checked the Admob site for warning messages, but i couldn't fine any. I also checked the payment details tab, but i saw a notification that says i don't have to worry about payments because i haven't reached my threshold amount.

I'm using Xamarin to display my Ad. My code looks like this :

```
Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.Initialize(this.Activity.ApplicationContext, "I put my ad unit id here");
```

The test Ad that i'm seeing :

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Should be because your app id and add unit id is not coded as expected.

Refer below link:

https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/

Comment: I have provided my ad unit id. I didn't want to specify it here. to prove that i've specified it, i'm able to view the test ad i.e  http://aldecode.com/implement-admob-banner-ads-android-application/    -> I see the medium rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the issue. I was using interstitial app id instead of banner app id. And i was also setting the app id in 2 locations : axml -> ads:adUnitId=""

and

cs -> Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.Initialize(this.Activity.ApplicationContext, "");.

Axml page was using the test app id, and the cs was using the live app id.

So i resolve the issue by removing app id from cs code completely, and setting the app id in the axml page only.